# visudo nopasswd not working

Tags: linux, sudo, sudoers, visudo

I am trying to allow all users in the admin group to run a `jar` file as SUDO without a password, I have edited the sudoers file (using visudo) and tried a number of commands but it still prompts me for a password every time

---

Contents of `/etc/sudoers`:

```
# /etc/sudoers
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#

Defaults        env_reset

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
# (Note that later entries override this, so you might need to move
# it further down)
%sudo ALL=(ALL) ALL
#
#includedir /etc/sudoers.d

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL
admin ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /opt/myapp/
admin ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /opt/myapp/myapp.jar
admin ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: java -jar /opt/myapp/myapp.jar
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try:

```
%admin ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/java -jar /opt/myapp/myapp.jar
```